# Cleaning Search History: Windows-10

Tags: windows-10

I am giving away my laptop without deleting my user account. I want to clean the hard disk as much as possible.

I have already **deleted the search history** and cleared **search indexing**. But still, as soon as I type any applications name, I start seeing suggestion about some related file names. The funny thing is, those do not exist on the computer anymore.

***How can I clear the recent suggestions?***

[image]

Comment: Use CCleaner as one tool of many to accomplish this.  Why not wipe the drive and reinstall?  It's crazy easy nowadays.  Also, why aren't you removing the account?

Comment: "without deleting my user account" thats just crazy.

Answer (score 0):

The search results shown are from the "recently opened items" for the App Jump lists, the pop-up menu when you right-click on an App.

To delete them through windows, go into "settings" and select the "Personalization" option. Once inside, select the "Start" option on the left-side menu, and look for the toggle for "Show recently opened items in Jump Lists..." on the right-side panel. Make sure you switch the toggle to "off" and it should clear the recent suggestions. There is an illustrated guide on [How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/236711/how-to-turn-off-recent-items-and-frequent-places-in-windows-10/), just be aware that the windows 10 shown there is an older version and may have slightly different options than current versions.